# Generics method with predicated core data search won’t return correct result

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, core-data

I’m trying to have a generic method that search entities for a chosen string inside an attribute to see how many such entities are there, which then will decide what number or lack of number to attach to the string as it was returned. I’ve shown it in the picture.[image: io] The entity type, the search string, and the attribute are all determined by input parameters. The problem is I cannot seem to make this generic method work consistently. On some projects it works, on others it doesn’t and the predicated search either returns an empty string or incomplete result. Can anyone help me figure it out? I’ve been scratching my head since last month.

Code:

```
private func getDefaultNameFor<T>Centityt T, defaultString: String, attribute: String)—>String{ 
var count = 0
var defaultName = defaultString

let type = T.self 
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: “\(type)”) 
let pred = NSPredicate(format: “%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@", attribute, defaultString) 
fetchRequest.predicate = pred 
var untitledEntities: [NSManagedObject] = [] 

do { 
     untitledEntities = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) 
}catch{ 
     print("error fetching existing default names: \(error)” 
}
count = untitledEntities.count 
print("pred rEturns: " untitledEntities.description) 
if count !=0 { 
     defaultName = defaultString + String(count) 
}
print("default name: " defaultName) 
return defaultName 
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant code as text. Code in images can't be copied into an answer and doesn't work with screen readers.

Comment: I don't see how making this function generic really helps. Why not just pass the entity type or just the entity name as a parameter. I can see how using the string description of a Swift type could be fragile. You should also set the fetch request result type to [`countResultType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequestresulttype/1506211-countresulttype) since you don't need the actual entries.

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry didn’t see it was countResultType. I’ll try that too. Also I’ve typed out the actual code.

Comment: @Paulw11 the reason I’m using a generic is that I’m using this method in many different places. So I wanted to save some repetition, but if that’s the problem than I guess I’ll just have to write it multiple times...

Comment: You can still use the function in many places without making it generic. You could just pass the entity name as a string or the type as a parameter as you do now; simply change the parameter type `T` to `Type` And make the function non- generic , sending the entity name as a string would be the approach I would use.

Comment: @ Paulw11 I’ll try the string input. Thanks! The other approach I’m not quite sure of. We’ll see if the problem will go away without using the generics.

Comment: @Paulw11 It didn’t work. I changed it from generic to taking a simple string as entity name, but the search still returns empty. I checked again at the pred but I don’t think it was formatted wrong. And I missing something?

Comment: @Paulw11 I think I’ve identified where the problem is from. It seems it is the first %@ for keypath of the attribute not working...

Comment: Don’t edit the question to include the answer. Add an actual Answer! Answering your own question is totally legal and in fact it’s good, helping others and closing the question in good order.

Comment: @matt Okay I’ve edited it back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keypaths are substituted with %K instead of %@. (format: “%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", attribute, defaultString) worked.
Nothing wrong with using the generic, although I think not using it might still be preferable. This was a very basic sort of error I hope I had caught earlier by reviewing the predicate formatting guide.

Here’s how I solved it:
1: as suggested, I changed it from generic to taking a simple string as entity name, but the search still returns empty. I checked again at the pred but I don’t think it was formatted wrong. Am I missing something?

2: okay so I just adjusted the pred to be a simple format: “name CONTAINS[cd] ‘untitled’” and it worked fine. So why is it not working in (format: “%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@", attribute, defaultString) ? I even tried to add ‘’ around the second %@ but result was still empty.

3: (format: “name CONTAINS[cd] %@", defaultString) is working fine. So I guess the problem is the first substitute not functioning as keypath in the predicate format. So how to make it function as so?

4: Solved it! Keypaths are substituted with %K instead of %@. (format: “%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", attribute, defaultString) worked. This is such a basic error. I cannot believe I’ve been bugged with this for a month almost.