# Core Data: How best to check uniqueness repeatedly? Save context? Fetch count?

Tags: ios, swift, validation, core-data, constraints

**Update**: I looked up core data validation(validateForInsert() on managedObhects) upon suggestion but somehow it is not catching the uniqueness constraint violations. I don’t know why because it looks like it should be pretty straightforward. I tried it on both the superclass managedObject type and particular entity types, on both parent and child contexts(on corresponding objects in each context) but nothing works. Although, I only tried it on UIManagedDocument so far. Validation sounds like a much better option but I’m getting frustrated I can’t make it work and haven’t got a clue why.

——

A while back I wrote a func to create default name for core data entities. Little did I know how much trouble it was getting me into… The first iteration of the func can be found in another (solved)question if you are interested(you don’t have to read that question to understand this one): < [Generics method with predicated core data search won’t return correct result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829345/generics-method-with-predicated-core-data-search-won-t-return-correct-result) >

The first iteration was working sort of ok. However, it didn’t consider if a gap exists between the numbers of existing default names. For example, if name, name1 and name3 exist simultaneously in database, a repetition of name3 would be created, and it won’t satisfy where names has to be unique.

So to solve that, I thought I should add a while-loop to check the uniqueness of the newly created names and increase count by 1 in each loop until it was indeed unique. This won’t always fill in the gap, but I just want the names to be unique. I’ll provide the code below but first, the problem I encountered was that it acts “funky.” Sometimes the name is nil when it shouldn’t(no error was caught) or an incorrect name that already exists. So my question is what is the problem with my code?Or can I do to find out what is the problem? Or maybe is there a better way to check for uniqueness other than checking uniqueness error by saving contexts? (Maybe should just fetch and count result instead?) Am I approaching this default name function wrong? I would appreciate any input and discussion.

Here are my codes. The setup is a UIManagedDocument, which automatically provides two contexts, a child and a parent. The parent is a background one. I’m only using the child for edit right now, but I did setup and check both for throwing uniqueness errors. I also set up uniqueness constraints for the attributes.(for simplicity, I omitted the error type I defined and the error type casts related to that.)

```
func checkUniqueness()throws {
    var mergeError: Error? = nil
    do{
        try childContext.save()
        childContext.parent!.performAndWait{
        do{
            childContext.parent!.save()
        }catch{
            mergeError = error
            print(“parent error”)
        }
    }catch{
        mergeError = error
        print(“child error”)
    }

    if mergeError != nil{
        if (mergeError! as NSError).code == 133021 && (mergeError! as NSError).domain == NSCocoaErrorDomain{
        throw someUniquenessErrorIDefined
        }else{
            throw someDataErrorIDefined
        }
    }
}
 
//can throw an error indicating func failed and name is set to nil
func setDefaultName<T>(entity:T, defaultString: String, attribute: String) throws {
try? context.save()
//initial values
var name = defaultString
var count = 0
var someError: Error? = nil
//fetch the count
let type = T.self 
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSNumber>(entityName: “\(type)”) 
let pred = NSPredicate(format: “%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", attribute, defaultString) 
fetchRequest.predicate = pred 
fetchRequest.resultType = .countResultType
do { 
let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) 
count = result.first!.intValue
}catch{ 
 throw someDataErrorIDefined
}
//
//loop to find unique value
repeat{
    do{
        if count != 0{
            name = defaultString + String(count)
        }
        (entity as! NSManagedObject).setValue(name, forKey: attribute)
        count += 1
        try checkUniqueness()
        someError = nil
    }catch{
        someError = error
    }
} while someError == someUniquenessErrorIDefined

if someError == someDataErrorIDefined{
    (entity as! NSManagedObject).setValue(nil, forKey: attribute)
    throw someError
}


}
```

I should add that the funky behaviors disappeared after I relaunched Xcode and I have not been able to reproduce them, but I’m just worried they will come up again. Maybe I shouldn’t check uniqueness this way at all? I just read that uniqueness constraints are the more performant way to insure uniqueness, but I’m not sure they are supposed to be used like this.